# If and only if condition on holomorphic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, holomorphic-functions

I am learning a bit of complex function theory on my own. I found a theorem in a paper that I can't seem to find a proof of. It reads as follows:

A complex function $f$ is holomorphic if and only if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$.

I understand that the differential operator is defined as $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)$. But how does one actually prove the above theorem? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Here is a reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations

Comment: You need to assume some smoothness on $f$-such as differentiability in the real sense- for that to be an equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows directly from the Cauchy-Riemann equations. By demanding that this differential operator is zero, you are simply demanding that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold.

Comment: Thanks! That makes more sense!